# Golang encoding/json Marshaler

Tags: go, interface

As stated in the `encoding/json` package documentation,

> Marshal traverses the value v recursively.
>   If an encountered value implements the Marshaler interface
>   and is not a nil pointer, Marshal calls its MarshalJSON method
>   to produce JSON.

Where exactly [in the code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/encoding/json/encode.go) is this test performed?

In another terms, how does `encoding/json` check if a value `v` of type `t` implements the `Marshaller` interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here :

[Golang encoding/json Marshaler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074404/golang-encoding-json-marshaler/31074533?noredirect=1#comment50172792_31074533)

```
if t.Implements(marshalerType) {
    return marshalerEncoder
}
```

Edit:
The link above has been updated to point to a specific version of Go, as @dave-c pointed out in comments below.

Comment: It's better to use [a link to a specific revision](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/883bc6ed0ea815293fe6309d66f967ea60630e87/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L358-360) (or at least [to a specific release branch](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.4/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L358-360)) for such things. The link you give is to the whatever the current version of that file on the "master" branch looks like and tomorrow line 356 might be completely different (e.g. if a function is added/removed earlier in that file).

Comment: Note as well, that they are using the reflect package and `t` is a `reflect.Type`. It's more common to see something like: `x, ok := v.(someInterfaceType)`; e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/malSK3qwpV